# Change toolbar text only for order history page

Tags: magento2.3, orders, toolbar, account-dashboard

I need to change text of toolbar amount just in order history page in customer dashboard and show only 5 items per page without displaying limiter. Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create  Plugin on `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager`  and  changed output of `getAvailableLimit`

**Plugin  Class:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace StackExchanges\Magento\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Theme\Block\Html;

class Pager
{

    public function afterGetAvailableLimit(
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager $subject,
        $result
    ) {
      if ($subject->getRequest()->getFullActionName() !== 'sales_order_history'){
          return $result;
      }
        return [7 => 7, 20 => 20, 50 => 50];
    }
}
```

- Put the pager.php at `app/code/{Vendor}/{module}/Plugin/Frontend/Magento/Theme/Block/Html`
- You have must have  `di.xml` at  `app/code/{Vendor}/{module}/etc/frontend/`
- `app/code/{Vendor}/{module}/composer.json`
- `module.xml` at `app/code/{Vendor}/{module}/etc`
  `app/code/{Vendor}/{module}/registration.php`

Comment: Where can i add this code please? Thank you

Comment: Thank you and where i put this code of plugin please?

Comment: I have override module of magento_ sales in a module, i put this code in history.php?

Comment: Module is available at https://github.com/devamitbera/magento-stackexchange/blob/master/StackExchanges-340596.zip

Comment: Thank you, can i add code in pager.php intp my history.php in my magento_sales override?

Comment: You don't need that

Comment: Thank you, what about change text in toolbar amout just in order history page?